# PySide2 Row and Column Creator

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, mysql, pyside

In short, I need help simplifying and optimizing this code because now that I have switched to a tree widget from 2 list widgets, loading the tables has increased by roughly 3-4 seconds (used to be almost instant). I would also like to shorten this function if possible.

```
--- Background Info ---
self.tableData -- The table that the information is being displayed to
getItem() -- a function that when a table of a database is selected, returns the database name (var[0]) and the table name (var[1])
columnNames -- Returns the column names for the table
rows -- returns the total number of rows in the table
g -- index value for the row
h -- index value for the column the data will go in

-- forgot what i, j, k do because i was working on other parts of the program, but they are needed (been some time now)
```

Note: This code belongs to a class which I have not included

```
def LoadTable():
    self.tableData.clear()
    if getItem() != None:
        var = getItem()
        try:
            ccnnxx = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.uname.text(), password=self.upass.text(), host=self.uhost.text(), port=self.uport.text(), database = var[0])
            cursor = ccnnxx.cursor()
            self.tableData.setRowCount(0)
            self.tableData.setColumnCount(0)
            header = self.tableData.horizontalHeader()       
            item = getItem()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM " + var[1])
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            self.tableData.setRowCount(cursor.rowcount)
            ccnnxx.close()
            self.tableData.setColumnCount(len(rows[0]))
            columnNames = [a[0] for a in cursor.description]
            g = 0
            h = 0
            i = 0
            j = 0
            k = 0
            counter = 0
            for items in columnNames:
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                self.tableData.setHorizontalHeaderItem(g, item)
                self.tableData.horizontalHeaderItem(g).setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", columnNames[h], None, -1))
                header.setSectionResizeMode(g, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
                g += 1
                h += 1
            for row in rows:
                counter += 1
                if i < counter:
                    while j != len(rows[0]):
                        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                        self.tableData.setItem(i, k, item)
                        self.tableData.item(i, k).setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", str(row[j]), None, -1))
                        k +=1
                        j +=1
                    else:
                        i +=1
                        k = 0
                        j = 0
                else:
                    k = 0
                    j = 0
        except IndexError:
            #print('This table has no information!')
            pass
        except TypeError:
            #double right-click protection
            pass
     else:
         pass
```